# How to split nodes in regression trees

Tags: estimation, random-forest, cart, computational-statistics

I am looking for a comparison of different regression tree node splitting approaches within the random forest framework. I am looking at the trade-off between ensemble accuracy/reliability (holding forest size constant) and computational complexity of the split since I deal with large datasets.

The standard approach is to minimise $$\sum_{i \in \text{Region}_1} (y_i - \text{mean}(y_i)_{\text{Region}_1})^2 +\sum_{i \in \text{Region}_2} (y_i - \text{mean}(y_i)_{\text{Region}_2})^2$$ But another approach I have seen in a PhD thesis which drastically reduces the computational complexity is to look at the average of $$\frac{(\sum_{i \in \text{Region}_1} y_i)^2}{(\text{Cardinality of Region}_1)}$$ versus the same for $\text{Region}_2$; this allows me to use a running sum of $y_i$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compute variance with the same cost as the averages. Simply put you have to use an on-line version of algorithm for computing variance. It is crystal clear explained on [an article of John D. Cook](http://www.johndcook.com/skewness_kurtosis.html).
I used myself this online computing for a [regression tree - split numeric method](https://github.com/padreati/rapaio/blob/master/rapaio/src/rapaio/ml/tree/TreeRegressor.java) where I use an [online computation of variance](https://github.com/padreati/rapaio/blob/master/src/rapaio/core/stat/OnlineStat.java). I used to compute 2 running statistics, one starting from left and another one starting from right. It is possible to do that in a single step, I considered however that multiplication by a constant, gives also linear time and that does not bother me.

For more information you can take a look on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm) also.

Comment: Very nice. What do you mean by 'constant time'. Wouldn't it be linear time?

Comment: Sorry, I was meaning multiplication by a constant time, since I compute 2 running statistics. I will correct that in the answer.

Comment: How do you handle the large amounts of noise in the variance estimate in the first few iterations (whether starting from front or back of the vector)?

Comment: @Jase I do not have an answer. What I usually do in practice is to adjust the parameter which decides the minimum number of instances in a node. If there is plenty of data, then is no problem to have a large value for this minimum. If it is not, then I try to take a look at my data and understand from the underlying distribution which would be a proper value for this parameter.
I imagine that one could automate that by trying to estimate a confidence interval for the variance estimation, but I never tried to work on that.

Comment: The 'regression tree.' link is invalid.

Comment: @honeytidy problem solved